# Selenium WebElement xpath Java

Tags: java, xml, selenium, xslt, xpath

I am trying to navigate through a web page with xpath and I am coming up with some mixed results. This is what I am using:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'x-grid3-cell-inner x-grid3-col-0')]"));
```

That actually works great but the problem I am running into this this:

```
<div class="x-grid3-cell-inner x-grid3-col-0" unselectable="on">92300</div>
<div class="x-grid3-cell-inner x-grid3-col-0" unselectable="on">92475</div>
<div class="x-grid3-cell-inner x-grid3-col-0" unselectable="on">92476</div>
<div class="x-grid3-cell-inner x-grid3-col-0" unselectable="on">92301</div>
<div class="x-grid3-cell-inner x-grid3-col-0" unselectable="on">92474</div>
```

When I run that xpath in my Selenium test I always get the first div. How do I edit my xpath to retrieve the 4th div (92301) or some other div that isn't the first one in the list?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use this XPath `(//div[contains(@class, 'x-grid3-cell-inner x-grid3-col-0')])[4]` to get 4<sup>th</sup> `div`.

To find `div` which contains `92301` text, use this XPath:

```
//div[contains(text(), '92301')]
```

Comment: Thank you, Kirill! That works great but sometimes user insert data before or after what I am looking for which could change the position. Is there a different way to find the div with 92301 if several new divs have been written in front of it?

Answer (score 3):

you can use either `WebElement.findElements()` :

```
driver.findElements(By.xpath(...)).get(3)
```

or modify xpath to:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//div[contains(@class, 'x-grid3-cell-inner x-grid3-col-0')])[4]"));
```

Comment: Thanks, mantrid. That is super helpful. It gets me what I'm after. I am also going to keep looking for a more dynamic way of doing this as what I am after may not always be at position 4.